# Adjustment of a button position in mobile

Tags: css, sapui5

I want to adjust the position of a button depending on the mobile device used.

[image: Current button position]
<sup>(Current button position)</sup>

I want to adjust the position of <kbd>Click here</kbd> according to the mobile device.

So far, I have come up with the following code to handle adjustment (in `onRouteMatched`):

```
this.getView().byId('idBtn').onAfterRendering = function() {
  jQuery.sap.delayedCall(100, this, function() {
    var btnClnt = this.getView().byId("idBtn").getDomRef().getBoundingClientRect();
    if (sap.ui.Device.system.phone === true) {
      var marginTopVal = "";
      /*if (sap.ui.Device.os.name === "iOS") {
        jQuery(this.getDomRef()).css({
          'margin-top': '355px'
        });
        return;
      }*/

      // Portrait mode

      if (sap.ui.Device.resize.width === 375) { //- 305 for iphone6 on fiori client via cloud launchpad
        marginTopVal = window.innerHeight - btnClnt.bottom - 305;
        jQuery(this.getDomRef()).css({
          'margin-top': String(marginTopVal + "px")
          //'margin-top': '300px'
        });
      } else if (sap.ui.Device.resize.width === 360) { // -165 works properly on andriod fiori client via cloud launchpad
        marginTopVal = window.innerHeight - btnClnt.bottom - 165;
        jQuery(this.getDomRef()).css({
          'margin-top': String(marginTopVal + "px")
          //'margin-top': '180px'
        });
      }
    }
  });
}
```

In the below screenshot, you can see the position of button changes.

[image: iPhone X screenshot]

I want to keep its position fixed on every Android and iOS mobile devices.

Please suggest how to fix the position of button at one place.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe “FlexBox” solves your Problem?
Please test the following example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Centered button</title>

    <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap' src='/sapui5/resources/sap-ui-core.js' data-sap-ui-theme='sap_belize' data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'
      data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>

    <script id="myXml" type="text/xmldata">
      <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="myController" displayBlock="true">
        <App>
          <Page title="Centered Button">
            <FlexBox height="100%" alignItems="Center" justifyContent="Center">
              <items>
                <Button text="Start" />
              </items>
            </FlexBox>
          </Page>
        </App>
      </mvc:View>
    </script>

    <script>
      sap.ui.controller("myController", {});
      sap.ui.xmlview({
        viewContent: jQuery('#myXml').html()
      }).placeAt("content");
    </script>

  </head>

  <body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: FlexBox (or HBox or VBox) is definitely the right approach here. Would just like to add that you can also use the Device model to adjust layout configuration dynamically based on device. Link to the docs:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d63a15e5eebb45cdada317bae5f45bc2

Answer (score 0):

Generally SAPUI5 uses container controls so that UI5 adapts a screen layout according to the screen size. In the UX Design Guidelines, [there is an article](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/responsiveness-adaptiveness/.).

For example, the control sap.m.Page contains header and footers that are adapted by UI5 according to the size of the screen. Icons and Buttons in there controls are then aligned by UI5 on different screem sozes.

Comment: I have added CSS to the button and it does not look rectangle in shape instead it has a circular shape. SAPUI5 controls are only responsive if you do not add any custom css to them.